# Why some asp.net developers encrypt ConnectionStrings?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration-files

I seen some asp.net developers encrypt ConnectionStrings that was included in separate config file.
 Why they did that ? I know that config files are unreadable from the client side/browser! Is it possible to access to this kind of files ?

Comment: You can encrypt _any_ configuration sections. It does not have to be in a separate config file.

Comment: I know that, but i said that to be clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't rule out that the web box is compromised.
Also, you don't want the web admins to know passwords to databases.

You need to remember that config files cannot be obtained by the browser just because `.config` extension is in the list of restrictions in IIS metadata. It may be possible to get them from the server in other way or some misconfiguration problem may allow them to be downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

They can be accessed by maintenance personnel, backup operators or others that have access to the disk without going through the website. That´s one example.

Answer (score 3):

If you upload your web.config file with custom errors set to "off", any errors produced by your web application will display your code. This could even include lines from your config files and this could include the "ConnectionStrings" making them visible to the public.

Comment: This is a different issue, I believe. Your exceptions will contains the full connection string in plain text even if config section is encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

To every organization the most important thing to them is their **data**

1. This is done where there are multiple developers working on the same
   application
2. Sometimes, new developers are also enrolled in the team. Exposing each & every aspect of your database, system, login name, machine name is never a good approach
3. There is chance of information leak in production, testing Q/A phase etc.
4. This comes really handy when there is a code theft within an organization, atleaset your data is safe from an outside intrusion as the connection strings were encrypted
5. Can you bear the risk if someone has access to your database & perform a table/schema drop or a delete all from your tables?
   [MSDN: How to secure connection strings when using a datasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)